# How to use many to one relation ship in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I have a supplierranking table as follow

```
Class Supplierrank extends Eloquent{
    public function supplier(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Supplier','supplierid','id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User','userid','id');
    }

}
```

I am trying to do this query

```
$usersandranking= Supplierrank::with('supplier')->with(array('user'=>function($query) use($exceleve){
        $query->where('event','=',$exceleve);
    }))->orderBy('userid')->orderBy('rank')->get();
```

here you can see I am trying to fetch supplierranking for all the user where event == execelevent

but the query is fetching me all the users from user table

any Idea where I am doing it wrong

The user table looks like this

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function answer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Answer','user_id');
    }

    public function supplierranking(){
        return $this->hasMany('Supplierrank','userid','id');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
after using 
DB::enableQueryLog() ;
and 
dd(DB::getQueryLog());

I got this

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(44) "select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(71) } ["time"]=> float(0.59) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(39) "select * from `users` where `event` = ?" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "Design Mission South Africa 2015" } ["time"]=> float(3.41) } [2]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(63) "select * from `supplierranks` order by `userid` asc, `rank` asc" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(366.02) } [3]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(1051) "select * from `suppliers` where `suppliers`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ["bindings"]=> array(333) { [0]=> int(41) [1]=> int(43) [2]=> int(33) [3]..................
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `DB::enableQueryLog()` and then  `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` and post the query

Comment: @BasheerAhmed where should I put this in my controller

Comment: Before Querying put this code `DB::enableQueryLog()` and after query put this one `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` also you need to import the db class at the top `use DB`

Comment: @BasheerAhmed its lot of content where should I dump it and send you the url

Comment: [Post it here](http://laravel.io/bin) for that you need to login with github If you don't have git hub account try [this one](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)

Comment: Are you sure $exceleve is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @BasheerAhmed here is the link http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d4d5d3d1798f420a3340c7a24857f306cf2a7bd

I have also updated in my question

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode yes its correct

Comment: So it means `$exceleve` has All users id, isn't it?

Comment: @BasheerAhmed no it has event name , so I am getting all the users who belongs to excelevent

Comment: with('supplier') should be with(['supplier'])->

Comment: @Vikram oh Sorry I just figuer out you want all suppliers etc for the current autheticated user. If that's the case the let me know!

Comment: @Janko that doesn't make sense

Comment: @BasheerAhmed see this is what I want , I am trying to get all the supplieranking for the users whos event is equal to exceleve

Comment: @Janko its not working

Comment: @Vikram Hold on while I just try it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95892/discussion-between-vikram-and-basheer-ahmed).